# mysql: how to select with string containing "-"

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone please point me where did I go wrong?
I've an apps using PHP and mysql. The thing is, we are using some file uploader plugins that require us to save the unique id that has format something like this `a41ddc78-3fee-4bf3-88c1-83028ae22f1`. At some point, I need to select data from the database using this fields and as you can see, I can't get the field when I do manual query on it. any help is appreciate on how to solve this problem. Thank you

[image: My database entry]

[image: After Query]

Comment: The value in the Db has a 4 at the end. you've spelt your string wrong

Comment: The UUID is actually `a41ddc78-3fee-4bf3-88c1-83028ae22f14`, with a `4` at the end.  Voting to close as a typo question.  And also, you might want to use single quotes around the UUID instead of double quotes.  Not mandatory, just the more common convention.

Comment: I thank you guys for pointing what I doing wrong.. Please Close the question already, feel embarrassed for making this clumsy mistake. My apps has trimmed the last character for some reason and already fixed it.. once again thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM product_image WHERE unique_id = 'a41ddc78-3fee-4bf3-88c1-83028ae22f1'
```

the query works fine...

Comment: Really? OP just said that it didn't.

Comment: thanks, I had found my mistake .. Thanks and I vote to close this questions.